# How to construct first order differential equation that solution would be $y=(x+C)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

please help.
I have no clue how to construct first order diff. equation when the solution is already given $y=(x+C)^2$. Though I can do it vice versa.
I just need some hints.

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=2(x+C)$$
$$C=\frac{y'-2x}{2}$$
$$y=(x+\frac{y'-2x}{2})^2$$
$$y=(y'/2)^2$$

Comment: @Rsn you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

A first order differential equation features the function $y$ and its derivative $y'$. So just differentiate the equation:
$$
y = (x + C)^2 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2(x + C)
$$
We can get rid of the constant $C$ by expressing the RHS in terms of $y$:
$$
x + C = \sqrt{y} \Rightarrow \\
y' = 2 \sqrt{y}
$$

Comment: So the answer is $y'=2x+2C$? lol

Comment: You can get rid of the $C$ by looking to express the RHS in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

typically $C$ is a constant of integration which does not appear in the original d.e.

since we have $y=(x+C)^2$ and $y'= 2(x+C)$

I suggest something like

$$(y')^2 = 4y$$